# Combine a lot of tables with a prefix into one view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have imported from the database of a program about 50 tables that share the same structure, but different name, all with same prefix:

- prefx_abc4
- prefx_adr3
- prefx_ubr6
- etc.

I want to merge them into one single view without having to manually write all the names with `UNION ALL`, and also in one column display that name:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a little help from dynamic SQL and assuming same structures

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '>>>'
Select @SQL=Replace(COALESCE(@SQL,'')+' Union All Select *,TableName='''+TABLE_NAME+''' From [' + TABLE_NAME +']','>>> Union All ','')  
  From  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables 
  Where Table_Name Like 'PREFIX%'

Select @SQL
--Exec(@SQL)
```

Comment: Ok this works, but I have been searching and there is no way to save this as a view. (no dynamic sql is allowed)

Comment: Exec('Create View [dbo].[MyViewName] as '+@SQL)